# Matplotlib Scatter Plot Returns Different Plots in Different Versions

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, generative-art

I'm working on a generative art generator library for python called [samila](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/samila) based on matplotlib scatter plot. It gets two functions and maps a square space into a arbitrary shape. We want the generated shape to be the same for given functions and given random seed in order to be reproducible.

Recently we were working on functions with complex values and notified that scatter plot output is not the same in different versions on matplotlib.

**I wanted to know why is it like this and what's the problem with matplotlib. If this is a bug it could be horrible for matplotlib to plot different figures for a specific code in its different versions.**

So if you run bellow code using `matplotlib==3.4.3`:

```
from samila import *
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f1(x, y):
    return math.cos(x**2 * y)**1.926 - math.floor(x - y)**1.861 - math.floor(y**2 * x)**1.688

def f2(x, y):
    return x - y**1.617 - math.ceil(y)**1.477 - abs(x**2 * y) ** 1.647 - math.cos(x * y)**1.668

GI = GenerativeImage(f1, f2)
GI.generate(seed=755398)
GI.plot(color=(0.159, 0.085, 0.191), projection=Projection.POLAR, spot_size=2)
GI.save_image('art.png')
plt.show()
```

You'll have bellow warning :

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:136: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
```

With bellow generated art:
[image: Samila Art for matplotlib==3.4.3]

---

And if you run the code using `matplotlib==3.0.3` you'll have:

```
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:136: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
```

[image: Samila Art for matplotlib==3.0.3]

---

[Edit] : I added a example which uses `matplotlib` directly instead of using it through Samila. If you prefer you can use this script instead of previous one.

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

def f1(x,y):
    return math.cos(x**2 * y)**1.926 - math.floor(x - y)**1.861 - math.floor(y**2 * x)**1.688
def f2(x,y):
    return x - y**1.617 - math.ceil(y)**1.477 - abs(x**2 * y) ** 1.647 - math.cos(x * y)**1.668
def float_range(start, stop, step):
    while start < stop:
        yield float(start)
        start += step


data1 = []
data2 = []
range1 = list(float_range(-1*math.pi, math.pi, 0.01))
range_prod = list(itertools.product(range1, range1))
for item in range_prod:
    data1.append(f1(item[0], item[1]))
    data2.append(f2(item[0], item[1]))

color = (0.159, 0.085, 0.191)
spot_size = 0.01
projection = "polar"

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 10)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=projection)
ax.scatter(
        data2,
        data1,
        alpha=0.1,
        edgecolors=color,
        s=spot_size)
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.patch.set_zorder(-1)
ax.add_artist(ax.patch)

plt.show()
```

---

---

**System Details:**

- OS: Linux - Ubuntu 20.04
- Python: Python 3.8.10
- GCC: [GCC 9.3.0]
- Matplotlib: [3.0.3, 3.4.3]
- Numpy: 1.19.1

Comment: Thank you for mentioning I updated the question.

> I wanted to know why is it like this and what's the problem with matplotlib. If this is a bug it could be horrible for matplotlib to plot different figures for a specific code in its different versions.

Comment: Did you try calculating the real part inside the library? Did you consider using `numpy` instead of `math`?

Comment: @JohanC Yes I tried them. None of them solve it. Filtering the data in a way which just the real part exist did not make any difference and using `numpy` instead of `math` is adding a new warning `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars` but still no improvement.

Comment: Please include an example that doesn't rely on your library.  We really have no idea what `GI.plot` does.

Comment: @JodyKlymak You're right. Thank you for your point. I added a example at the end of the question which uses scatter directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that matplotlib changes its plotting strategy from `3.0.3` which ignores points with negative radius to `3.4.3` in which they're plotted.

I couldn't find this using [**compare release notes**](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/compare/v3.4.3...v3.0.3) and it was so confusing for me. Hope there will be an warning for this situation avoiding future issues.

I tested bellow code which is way simpler:

```
data1 = [-2, -5,  2, 2]
data2 = [-2, 2, -2, 2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="polar")
ax.scatter(
        data2,
        data1,
        s=30)

plt.show()
```

in `matplotlib.__version__ == 3.0.3` we got:

[image]

while in `matplotlib.__version__ == 3.4.3`:

[image]